# Rotations of a cube

Tags: 3d, rotations, symmetric-groups, computational-geometry, computational-mathematics

I am trying to create a program using Python 3 which must simulate the rotations of a cube.

However, I am struggling to figure out how to rotate that cube. I have the following formulas:

```
def rotate_x(self, angle):
    """ Rotates the point around the X axis by the given angle in degrees. """
    rad = angle * math.pi / 180
    cosa = math.cos(rad)
    sina = math.sin(rad)
    y = self.y * cosa - self.z * sina
    z = self.y * sina + self.z * cosa
    return Point3D(self.x, y, z)

def rotate_y(self, angle):
    """ Rotates the point around the Y axis by the given angle in degrees. """
    rad = angle * math.pi / 180
    cosa = math.cos(rad)
    sina = math.sin(rad)
    z = self.z * cosa - self.x * sina
    x = self.z * sina + self.x * cosa
    return Point3D(x, self.y, z)

def rotate_z(self, angle):
    """ Rotates the point around the Z axis by the given angle in degrees. """
    rad = angle * math.pi / 180
    cosa = math.cos(rad)
    sina = math.sin(rad)
    x = self.x * cosa - self.y * sina
    y = self.x * sina + self.y * cosa
    return Point3D(x, y, self.z)
```

I run these functions on each vertex of the cube to rotate it. However, my problem is: how do I generate a list of all the possible rotations of the cube - rotating only by multiples of 90$^{\circ}$ or by 0$^{\circ}$ around the **x, y, or z axes** - while avoiding duplicates? I can rotate multiple times. I know there are 24 rotations - but what I'm wondering is how to generate them.

What I'm looking for is a list of all possible rotations (for example: 90$^{\circ}$x, 180$^{\circ}$y; 270$^{\circ}$x, 90$^{\circ}$z; 180$^{\circ}$y; etc) and an explanation of how you got to this list.

Comment: Isn't a cube symmetric so a rotation of 90° doesn't change anything? Unless this is a die with 6 different sides. If it is, each side has four configurations for a total of 24 combinations.

Comment: @ja72 All the sides are different, and thanks for the comment but you didn't read the question. What I'm looking for is a list of all the combinations and an explanation of how they can be achieved by rotating the cube by factors of 90 degrees from a predefined starting position.

Comment: Do read about transformation matrix for 3D: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Examples_in_3D_computer_graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such problems are tackled in group theory.

My friend Ruby gave me this list of rotations and some of the aliases she knows:

```
rots = [
  k = 1: e=12345678 ["ee", "xxxx", "yyyy", "zzzz", "xexxx", "xxexx", "xxxex", "xxxxe", "yeyyy", "yyeyy", "yyyey", "yyyye", "zezzz", "zzezz", "zzzez", "zzzze"]
  k = 2: x=56218734 ["xe", "xee", "ex", "yxz", "xeee", "yexz", "yxez", "yxze", "xeeee", "xxxxx", "xyyyy", "xzzzz", "yeexz", "yexez", "yexze", "yxeez", "yxeze", "yxxzy", "yxzee", "yyxzz", "yyyyx", "yzyyy", "zxyyy", "zyxxz", "zyzyy", "zzxyy", "zzyzy", "zzzxy", "zzzyz", "zzzzx"]
  k = 3: y=41238567 ["ye", "ey", "yee", "zyx", "yeee", "zeyx", "zyex", "zyxe", "xxxxy", "xxxyz", "xxxzx", "xxyzz", "xxzxz", "xyzzz", "xzxzz", "xzyyx", "yeeee", "yxxxx", "yyyyy", "yzzzz", "zeeyx", "zeyex", "zeyxe", "zxzzz", "zyeex", "zyexe", "zyxee", "zyyxz", "zzyxx", "zzzzy"]
  k = 4: z=26731584 ["ze", "ez", "xzy", "zee", "xezy", "xzey", "xzye", "zeee", "xeezy", "xezey", "xezye", "xxxxz", "xxzyy", "xyxxx", "xzeey", "xzeye", "xzyee", "xzzyx", "yxyxx", "yxzzy", "yyxyx", "yyyxy", "yyyyz", "yyyzx", "yyzxx", "yzxxx", "zeeee", "zxxxx", "zyyyy", "zzzzz"]
  k = 5: xx=87654321 ["xex", "xxe", "xeex", "xexe", "exx", "xxee", "xyxz", "yxxy", "yxyz", "yxzx", "yyzz", "yzxz", "zxxz", "zzyy", "xeeex", "xeexe", "xexee", "xeyxz", "xxeee", "xyexz", "xyxez", "xyxze", "yexxy", "yexyz", "yexzx", "yeyzz", "yezxz", "yxexy", "yxeyz", "yxezx", "yxxey", "yxxye", "yxyez", "yxyze", "yxzex", "yxzxe", "yyezz", "yyzez", "yyzze", "yzexz", "yzxez", "yzxze", "zexxz", "zezyy", "zxexz", "zxxez", "zxxze", "zzeyy", "zzyey", "zzyye"]
  k = 6: xy=15624873 ["yz", "zx", "xey", "xye", "yez", "yze", "zex", "zxe", "xeey", "exy", "xeye", "xyee", "xzyx", "yeez", "yeze", "yxzy", "yzee", "zeex", "zexe", "zxee", "zyxz", "xeeey", "xeeye", "xeyee", "xezyx", "xyeee", "xzeyx", "xzyex", "xzyxe", "yeeez", "yeeze", "yexzy", "yezee", "yxezy", "yxzey", "yxzye", "yzeee", "zeeex", "zeexe", "zexee", "zeyxz", "zxeee", "zyexz", "zyxez", "zyxze"]
  k = 7: xz=67325841 ["xez", "xze", "xeez", "exz", "xeze", "xxzy", "xzee", "yxzz", "yyyx", "zyyy", "xeeez", "xeeze", "xexzy", "xezee", "xxezy", "xxzey", "xxzye", "xzeee", "yexzz", "yeyyx", "yxezz", "yxzez", "yxzze", "yyeyx", "yyyex", "yyyxe", "zeyyy", "zyeyy", "zyyey", "zyyye"]
  k = 8: yx=85147623 ["yex", "yxe", "eyx", "xzzz", "yeex", "yexe", "yxee", "yyxz", "zyxx", "zzzy", "xezzz", "xzezz", "xzzez", "xzzze", "yeeex", "yeexe", "yexee", "yeyxz", "yxeee", "yyexz", "yyxez", "yyxze", "zeyxx", "zezzy", "zyexx", "zyxex", "zyxxe", "zzezy", "zzzey", "zzzye"]
  k = 9: yy=34127856 ["yey", "yye", "eyy", "xxzz", "xyyx", "yeey", "yeye", "yyee", "yzyx", "zxyx", "zyxy", "zyyz", "zyzx", "zzxx", "xexzz", "xeyyx", "xxezz", "xxzez", "xxzze", "xyeyx", "xyyex", "xyyxe", "yeeey", "yeeye", "yeyee", "yezyx", "yyeee", "yzeyx", "yzyex", "yzyxe", "zexyx", "zeyxy", "zeyyz", "zeyzx", "zezxx", "zxeyx", "zxyex", "zxyxe", "zyexy", "zyeyz", "zyezx", "zyxey", "zyxye", "zyyez", "zyyze", "zyzex", "zyzxe", "zzexx", "zzxex", "zzxxe"]
  k = 10: zy=32674158 ["zey", "zye", "ezy", "xxxz", "xzyy", "yxxx", "zeey", "zeye", "zyee", "zzyx", "xexxz", "xezyy", "xxexz", "xxxez", "xxxze", "xzeyy", "xzyey", "xzyye", "yexxx", "yxexx", "yxxex", "yxxxe", "zeeey", "zeeye", "zeyee", "zezyx", "zyeee", "zzeyx", "zzyex", "zzyxe"]
  k = 11: zz=65872143 ["zez", "zze", "ezz", "xxyy", "xyzy", "xzxy", "xzyz", "xzzx", "yyxx", "yzzy", "zeez", "zeze", "zxzy", "zzee", "xexyy", "xeyzy", "xezxy", "xezyz", "xezzx", "xxeyy", "xxyey", "xxyye", "xyezy", "xyzey", "xyzye", "xzexy", "xzeyz", "xzezx", "xzxey", "xzxye", "xzyez", "xzyze", "xzzex", "xzzxe", "yeyxx", "yezzy", "yyexx", "yyxex", "yyxxe", "yzezy", "yzzey", "yzzye", "zeeez", "zeeze", "zexzy", "zezee", "zxezy", "zxzey", "zxzye", "zzeee"]
  k = 12: xxx=43781265 ["xexx", "xxex", "xxxe", "xeexx", "xexex", "xexxe", "exxx", "xxeex", "xxexe", "xxxee", "xxyxz", "xyxxy", "xyxyz", "xyxzx", "xyyzz", "xyzxz", "xzxxz", "xzzyy", "yxxyx", "yxyxy", "yxyyz", "yxyzx", "yxzxx", "yyxyy", "yyyzy", "yyzxy", "yyzyz", "yyzzx", "yzxxy", "yzxyz", "yzxzx", "yzyzz", "yzzxz", "zxxxy", "zxxyz", "zxxzx", "zxyzz", "zxzxz", "zyzzz", "zzxzz", "zzyyx"]
  k = 13: xxy=58761432 ["xyz", "xzx", "yzz", "zxz", "xexy", "xeyz", "xezx", "xxey", "xxye", "xyez", "xyze", "xzex", "xzxe", "yezz", "yzez", "yzze", "zexz", "zxez", "zxze", "xeexy", "xeeyz", "xeezx", "xexey", "exxy", "xexye", "xeyez", "xeyze", "xezex", "xezxe", "xxeey", "xxeye", "xxyee", "xxzyx", "xyeez", "xyeze", "xyxzy", "xyzee", "xzeex", "xzexe", "xzxee", "xzyxz", "yeezz", "yezez", "yezze", "yxxyy", "yxyzy", "yxzxy", "yxzyz", "yxzzx", "yyyxx", "yyzzy", "yzeez", "yzeze", "yzxzy", "yzzee", "zeexz", "zexez", "zexze", "zxeez", "zxeze", "zxxzy", "zxzee", "zyxzz", "zyyyx", "zzyyy"]
  k = 14: xxz=73268415 ["zyy", "xexz", "xxez", "xxze", "zeyy", "zyey", "zyye", "xeexz", "xexez", "exxz", "xexze", "xxeez", "xxeze", "xxxzy", "xxzee", "xyxzz", "xyyyx", "xzyyy", "yxxxy", "yxxyz", "yxxzx", "yxyzz", "yxzxz", "yyzzz", "yzxzz", "yzyyx", "zeeyy", "zeyey", "zeyye", "zxxzz", "zxyyx", "zyeey", "zyeye", "zyyee", "zyzyx", "zzxyx", "zzyxy", "zzyyz", "zzyzx", "zzzxx"]
  k = 15: xyx=48513762 ["yxy", "yyz", "yzx", "zxx", "xeyx", "xyex", "xyxe", "yexy", "yeyz", "yezx", "yxey", "yxye", "yyez", "yyze", "yzex", "yzxe", "zexx", "zxex", "zxxe", "xeeyx", "exyx", "xeyex", "xeyxe", "xxzzz", "xyeex", "xyexe", "xyxee", "xyyxz", "xzyxx", "xzzzy", "yeexy", "yeeyz", "yeezx", "yexey", "yexye", "yeyez", "yeyze", "yezex", "yezxe", "yxeey", "yxeye", "yxyee", "yxzyx", "yyeez", "yyeze", "yyxzy", "yyzee", "yzeex", "yzexe", "yzxee", "yzyxz", "zeexx", "zexex", "zexxe", "zxeex", "zxexe", "zxxee", "zxyxz", "zyxxy", "zyxyz", "zyxzx", "zyyzz", "zyzxz", "zzxxz", "zzzyy"]
  k = 16: xyy=21563487 ["yzy", "zxy", "zyz", "zzx", "xeyy", "xyey", "xyye", "yezy", "yzey", "yzye", "zexy", "zeyz", "zezx", "zxey", "zxye", "zyez", "zyze", "zzex", "zzxe", "xeeyy", "exyy", "xeyey", "xeyye", "xxxzz", "xxyyx", "xyeey", "xyeye", "xyyee", "xyzyx", "xzxyx", "xzyxy", "xzyyz", "xzyzx", "xzzxx", "yeezy", "yezey", "yezye", "yxxxz", "yxzyy", "yyxxx", "yzeey", "yzeye", "yzyee", "yzzyx", "zeexy", "zeeyz", "zeezx", "zexey", "zexye", "zeyez", "zeyze", "zezex", "zezxe", "zxeey", "zxeye", "zxyee", "zxzyx", "zyeez", "zyeze", "zyxzy", "zyzee", "zzeex", "zzexe", "zzxee", "zzyxz"]
  k = 17: xzz=78436512 ["yyx", "xezz", "xzez", "xzze", "yeyx", "yyex", "yyxe", "xeezz", "exzz", "xezez", "xezze", "xxxyy", "xxyzy", "xxzxy", "xxzyz", "xxzzx", "xyyxx", "xyzzy", "xzeez", "xzeze", "xzxzy", "xzzee", "yeeyx", "yeyex", "yeyxe", "yxzzz", "yyeex", "yyexe", "yyxee", "yyyxz", "yzyxx", "yzzzy", "zxyxx", "zxzzy", "zyxyx", "zyyxy", "zyyyz", "zyyzx", "zyzxx", "zzxxx"]
  k = 18: yxx=76583214 ["zzy", "yexx", "yxex", "yxxe", "zezy", "zzey", "zzye", "eyxx", "xxyyy", "xyxxz", "xyzyy", "xzxyy", "xzyzy", "xzzxy", "xzzyz", "xzzzx", "yeexx", "yexex", "yexxe", "yxeex", "yxexe", "yxxee", "yxyxz", "yyxxy", "yyxyz", "yyxzx", "yyyzz", "yyzxz", "yzxxz", "yzzyy", "zeezy", "zezey", "zezye", "zxxxz", "zxzyy", "zyxxx", "zzeey", "zzeye", "zzyee", "zzzyx"]
  k = 19: yyy=23416785 ["yeyy", "yyey", "yyye", "eyyy", "xxyxx", "xxzzy", "xyxyx", "xyyxy", "xyyyz", "xyyzx", "xyzxx", "xzxxx", "yeeyy", "yeyey", "yeyye", "yxxzz", "yxyyx", "yyeey", "yyeye", "yyyee", "yyzyx", "yzxyx", "yzyxy", "yzyyz", "yzyzx", "yzzxx", "zxxyx", "zxyxy", "zxyyz", "zxyzx", "zxzxx", "zyxyy", "zyyzy", "zyzxy", "zyzyz", "zyzzx", "zzxxy", "zzxyz", "zzxzx", "zzyzz", "zzzxz"]
  k = 20: zzz=51486237 ["zezz", "zzez", "zzze", "ezzz", "xxxyx", "xxyxy", "xxyyz", "xxyzx", "xxzxx", "xyxyy", "xyyzy", "xyzxy", "xyzyz", "xyzzx", "xzxxy", "xzxyz", "xzxzx", "xzyzz", "xzzxz", "yxyyy", "yyxxz", "yyzyy", "yzxyy", "yzyzy", "yzzxy", "yzzyz", "yzzzx", "zeezz", "zezez", "zezze", "zxxyy", "zxyzy", "zxzxy", "zxzyz", "zxzzx", "zyyxx", "zyzzy", "zzeez", "zzeze", "zzxzy", "zzzee"]
  k = 21: xxxy=84375126 ["xxyz", "xxzx", "xyzz", "xzxz", "yzzz", "zxzz", "zyyx", "xexxy", "xexyz", "xexzx", "xeyzz", "xezxz", "xxexy", "xxeyz", "xxezx", "xxxey", "xxxye", "xxyez", "xxyze", "xxzex", "xxzxe", "xyezz", "xyzez", "xyzze", "xzexz", "xzxez", "xzxze", "yezzz", "yzezz", "yzzez", "yzzze", "zexzz", "zeyyx", "zxezz", "zxzez", "zxzze", "zyeyx", "zyyex", "zyyxe"]
  k = 22: xxyx=14852376 ["xyxy", "xyyz", "xyzx", "xzxx", "yxyy", "yyzy", "yzxy", "yzyz", "yzzx", "zxxy", "zxyz", "zxzx", "zyzz", "zzxz", "xexyx", "xeyxy", "xeyyz", "xeyzx", "xezxx", "xxeyx", "xxyex", "xxyxe", "xyexy", "xyeyz", "xyezx", "xyxey", "xyxye", "xyyez", "xyyze", "xyzex", "xyzxe", "xzexx", "xzxex", "xzxxe", "yexyy", "yeyzy", "yezxy", "yezyz", "yezzx", "yxeyy", "yxyey", "yxyye", "yyezy", "yyzey", "yyzye", "yzexy", "yzeyz", "yzezx", "yzxey", "yzxye", "yzyez", "yzyze", "yzzex", "yzzxe", "zexxy", "zexyz", "zexzx", "zeyzz", "zezxz", "zxexy", "zxeyz", "zxezx", "zxxey", "zxxye", "zxyez", "zxyze", "zxzex", "zxzxe", "zyezz", "zyzez", "zyzze", "zzexz", "zzxez", "zzxze"]
  k = 23: xyxx=37842651 ["xzzy", "yxyx", "yyxy", "yyyz", "yyzx", "yzxx", "zxxx", "xeyxx", "xezzy", "xyexx", "xyxex", "xyxxe", "xzezy", "xzzey", "xzzye", "yexyx", "yeyxy", "yeyyz", "yeyzx", "yezxx", "yxeyx", "yxyex", "yxyxe", "yyexy", "yyeyz", "yyezx", "yyxey", "yyxye", "yyyez", "yyyze", "yyzex", "yyzxe", "yzexx", "yzxex", "yzxxe", "zexxx", "zxexx", "zxxex", "zxxxe"]
  k = 24: xyyy=62157348 ["yxxz", "yzyy", "zxyy", "zyzy", "zzxy", "zzyz", "zzzx", "xeyyy", "xyeyy", "xyyey", "xyyye", "yexxz", "yezyy", "yxexz", "yxxez", "yxxze", "yzeyy", "yzyey", "yzyye", "zexyy", "zeyzy", "zezxy", "zezyz", "zezzx", "zxeyy", "zxyey", "zxyye", "zyezy", "zyzey", "zyzye", "zzexy", "zzeyz", "zzezx", "zzxey", "zzxye", "zzyez", "zzyze", "zzzex", "zzzxe"]
]
```

Note that $xy$ means the composition $x \circ y$, thus first applying $y$ and then applying $x$.

Here is the [chat log](https://gist.github.com/mvw/db0b53a9f07e4e2c96f9) and here is [what I told Ruby about the problem](https://gist.github.com/mvw/1d7bf6ed0a9f6cfef778). The latter one includes fancy ASCII graphics which explain how the permutations were defined.

The key ideas are

- to describe the rotations as permutations on the eight labeled
  vertices of a cube
- every rotation is a composition of the four basic rotations $e, x, y, z$
- we generate compositions by using base $4$ numbers, which got the digits $0, 1, 2, 3$ and then counting from $0$ to $4^n-1$ which gives sequences from length $1$ to length $n$ (due to the normalization of leading zero digit and the rules of addition not all combinations with possible $e$ rotations show up, but all the combinations for $x,y,z$ should occur)
- we keep a hash dictionary which uses the permutation string as key and a permutation object plus a list of known alias name strings as value to sort into the expected $6\cdot 4 = 24$ equivalence classes

It should be possible to just use $x,y,z$ rotations, but then one needs a different mechanism to generate the tree of possible compositions. Counting seemed a quick hack.

> For example, if you rotate a cube 90 degrees around the x axis and
>   then 180 degrees around the y axis, it's the same as rotating it 270
>   degrees around the x axis and then 180 degrees around the z axis.

These would be the compositions $yyx$ and $zzxxx$, which fall into the equivalence class $k = 17$.

References:

- [Symmetry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_group)
- [Rotational symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry)
- [Rotation group SO(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO%283%29)
- [The Rotational Symmetries of the Cube](http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/math4160w03/cubesyms/)
- [The Rotations of a Cube](http://www.markronan.com/mathematics/symmetry-corner/the-rotations-of-a-cube/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but to clarify, I am only able to rotate this cube _around the x, y, or z axis_, and that means _only by multiples of 90 degrees_.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your answer, but I'm looking for a **list** of all those rotations without duplicates because there are some duplicates that are not immediately obvious. For example, if you rotate a cube 90 degrees around the x axis and then 180 degrees around the y axis, it's the same as rotating it 270 degrees around the x axis and then 180 degrees around the z axis.

Comment: Could you explain that please?

Comment: I added the stuff you needed for you.

Comment: What is a fundamental rotation about $\hat{e}$?

Comment: I changed the wording. All the rotations that result by combining $x$, $y$ and $z$ rotations end up resulting in one of twenty four permutations of the solid cube, forming a partition (or a set of equivalence classes) of all such rotations. The first such rotation of each equivalence class that gets discovered during search is used as representative of the equivalence class (this one I meant by the bogus wording), the ones discovered later are stored as alias.

Comment: Instead of permuting vertices you could also permute the 6 cube faces, as each such rotation is characterized by a unique mapping of faces to faces. of the unit cube. I don't understand the 'e' transformations though, if those are the identity transform, aren't they redundant?

Comment: Yes, I named the $e$ as "eins" (German for "one"), the multiplicative identity, the multiplication here the composition of transforms. The tranfsormations can be seen as elements of a symmetry group which acts on the vertices, and while $e$ does not result in a change, it is still a valid transformation and thus belongs to the group. With faces we can pick the first face from 6, and a second face from 4 possible choices, so its 24 configurations again.